# Chrome extension: Использование ресурса из extension chrome.extension.getURL('script.js')

Tags: chrome-extension

Пытаюсь повторить пример из ответа от Rob W:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602022/chrome-extension-retrieving-global-variable-from-webpage/9636008#9636008

Пример в целом рабочий за исключением того что не удается получить нормальную ссылку на инъектируемый script.js, который хранится в директории расширения.

Если script.js положить на локальный веб сервер - то все работает.

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли инъектировать js файл, который хранится в директории расширения в web страницу?

У меня отображается такая ошибка :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Инъектирование скрипта",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
    "*://*/script.js/"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "content_scripts": [
    {

      "js": ["content_script.js"],
      "matches": ["file:///*/*.html"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]

}
```

content_script.js:

```
let a = document.createElement('div');
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode('текст'));
document.body.appendChild(a);


var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
// s.src="http://localhost/script.js";
console.log (s.src);
console.log(s);
document.body.appendChild(s);

// Event listener
document.addEventListener('RW759_connectExtension', function(e) {
    // e.detail contains the transferred data (can be anything, ranging
    // from JavaScript objects to strings).
    // Do something, for example:
    alert(e.detail);
});
```

script.js:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   /* Example: Send data from the page to your Chrome extension */
   document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('RW759_connectExtension', {
       detail: 'GLOBALS' // Some variable from Gmail.
   }));
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

В manufest.json надо добавить такую секцию и все заработает:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "script.js"
  ]
```